# Table indexes for autocomplete in MySQL

Tags: mysql, like

I need to implement an "autocomplete-like" query in MySQL, one on a fairly short textual field `varchar(11)` and one on a potentially long field `varchar(140)`.

As they are autocomplete query, they will be LIKE-query. What sort of indexes I need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really big choice - it will be normal B-Tree index

with autocomplete You can not use FullText because it work only with full words

at the same time queries like:

```
SELECT text FROM tag_table WHERE text LIKE 'part_text%';
```

will use indexes

add:

in case of big column -

You of course could try to realise auto-complete by whole words - there You can create full text index, but not sure - how good it will work, because with fulltext always a lot of variants at the begin of search phrase, and variants how suggested text will be relevant to expected result

Comment: `because it work only with full words`. but no. you can do `word*`  to match non complete words